# Update column with random value

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-update

I have a table:

```
ID | VALUE | DATE
1  | 5     | 2012-10-01 
2  | 7     | 2012-10-02
3  | 3     | 2012-10-05
4  | 0     | 2012-05-07
```

I want to add on **the top of the current value** with the VALUE random **individually** BETWEEN 1 AND 5.

Let say:

```
ID | VALUE | RANDOM VALUE
1  | 5     | 0
2  | 7     | 2
3  | 3     | 3
4  | 0     | 6
```

NEW VALUE

```
ID | VALUE 
1  | 5     
2  | 9     
3  | 6     
4  | 6
```

How do I do this? All I can think of is by doing cursor type of query.

Any help?

Comment: Example is here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: try this `UPDATE table1 SET VALUE=(select RAND() from table1 as innertable) WHERE table1.id=innertable.id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE=VALUE+ROUND(1+RAND()*4);
```

Comment: Actually .. need to update each record randomly NOT update all records with 1 random value

Comment: I think the RHS of the set expression will get evaluated at each row. But if I happen to be wrong, try this one:  `UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE=VALUE+ROUND(1+RAND()*4-VALUE);` As this value seems to be dependant from the optimizer's point of view, this has to run for each row...

Comment: @ppeterka: The `RAND()` function is non-deterministic and, as such, it will be reevaluated for each updated record - see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/632dc/1/0).

Comment: @eggyal I thought this too, but wasn't sure, and I don't have a MySQL right now to try it out, that's why I provided a solution that would circumvent the theoretical problem...

Comment: @ppeterka: Almost close though. I can see that UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE=VALUE+ROUND(1+RAND()*4-VALUE) it given me each random value for each record. BUT I want to add from the previous value so for instance ID=5 has 5 value and after random (let say 2) so the value is 5 + 2 = 7

Answer (score 5):

This will update the value by a random value between 1 and 5

```
UPDATE TABLEA SET VALUE=FLOOR(RAND()*5)+1
```

Comment: Actually .. need to update each record randomly NOT update all records with 1 random value

Comment: @dcalliances: The `RAND()` function is non-deterministic and, as such, it will be reevaluated for each updated record - see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9f59/1/0).

Comment: @dcalliances how many rows you have in your table? what if you have more than 5 rows?