# Update table with random values from given set of string values

Tags: mysql, random

I want update my table with random values from given set, not from another table.

e.g. value1, value2, value3

and MySQL query should be update all records from above values.

I am looking similar type of solution but with random string values from given set:
[Update column with random value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972470/update-column-with-random-value)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `floor(rand()*3)` to generate a random number among 0, 1, and 2, then use `case when` to assign value

```
update test
set i = (case floor(rand()*3) 
         when 0 then 0 
         when 1 then 10 
         when 2 then 20 
         end);
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4f31/1)

Answer (score 41):

I would use the `elt()` function:

```
update tablename
    set columnname = elt(floor(rand()*3) + 1, 'value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

`elt()` chooses a particular element from a list.  `rand()` produces a random values.

Comment: Love this function. Very useful if you 18,600 UK postcodes you want to randomly populate a table with. I would have had to create a php script or something if I thought I would have had to do a `case, when, then` for 18k values!

Answer (score 5):

Try with [CEIL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) and [RAND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `column`=(CASE CEIL(RAND()*3)
              WHEN 1 THEN 'value1'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'value2'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'value3'
          END);
```

Comment: Hi, I want to use this, but by selecting reference data from a foreign key MS SqlServer Db table, can you show me this with select random (maybe 3 or 4 values) from a Ref table and update the current table with that.

Answer (score 1):

Rand() returns the same value for all the rows within a given call. Use newid() to get a random number for every row.

https://web.archive.org/web/20071228004107/http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-6089823.html

```
Update dbo.Employees 
Set City= (Case abs(checksum(NewId()) % 3)
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Lndon'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New York'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Paris'
    END
        );
```